# Transaction involving contract and ETH

Tags: web3js, ether, etherscan, logs

I have a problem in Web3. I'm trying to obtain data from an ETH [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4bad5eceba8501b62b9307c002957eb2a9ac5eb4ee8bc39340c801eb2abc93da) but it involves a contract (Coinbase 10). From what I understand of the transaction, it looks a lot like token transactions (like USDT, for example), but there are no tokens, just ETH. The problem with this is that this type of transaction normally comes with complete data in the `logs` field, but because it is ETH, the `logs` always comes empty (ETH transactions do not generate logs) :(.

The method I use to obtain transaction data individually is [getTransactionReceipt](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.0/web3-eth.html#gettransactionreceipt), but as I said,

If there was some method of obtaining a record of several transactions (e.g. getBlock) and already had this data, it would be great.

Transaction:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4bad5eceba8501b62b9307c002957eb2a9ac5eb4ee8bc39340c801eb2abc93da

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate a little on what we are trying to achieve here? 

If you want to get all the internal transactions, you would be able to do that using the trace https://www.quicknode.com/docs/ethereum/trace_transaction
 or 
debug https://www.quicknode.com/docs/ethereum/debug_traceTransaction
calls.

Comment: perfect, so worked for me